# Why is this simple program crashing?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

I basically have a structure with a student's information in it. After it takes the last input it crashes. The last printf is never presented and my compiler doesn't find any errors.

```
struct stud_prof {
    char student_name[NAME_LIMIT];
    char ssn_number[SSN_LIMIT];
    double gpa;
    int units;
    char major_code;
} student1;



int main(void)
{
    printf( "What is the student's name?\n" );
    scanf(" %s", &student1.student_name);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf( "What is the student's Social Security number?\n" );
    scanf(" %s", &student1.ssn_number);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf( "What is the student's GPA?\n" );
    scanf(" %lf", &student1.gpa);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf( "How many units has the student completed?\n" );
    scanf(" %d", &student1.units);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf( "Enter the student's Major Code.\n" );
    scanf( " %s", &student1.major_code);

    printf( " %s, %s, %f, %d, %s ", student1.student_name, 
    student1.ssn_number, student1.gpa, student1.units, student1.major_code);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard.

Comment: What is the value of `SSN_LIMIT`? Did you leave enough room for the trailing null?

Comment: ok? and that means it's in a different header file?

Comment: `scanf( " %s", &student1.major_code);`  should be `scanf( " %c", &student1.major_code);`

Comment: How many bytes are going to be put into student1.major_code, I wonder?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger** `gdb`.

Comment: i thought i did but i didnt take the dashes into account.

Comment: the major code is a 4 digit number that I won't be doing math with

Comment: Then it should either be `char[5]`, or it should be `unsigned int` and you read it with `%u`.

Comment: "my compiler doesn't find any errors." - Welcome to level 3: **The Debugger**

Comment: Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files you have included?   Without those include statements, the posted code does not compile.  Do you expect us to debug your code when you have not posted all the code?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input/format specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer to avoid the user overflowing the buffer.  Such buffer overflow is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour, but it's most likely not the cause of the problem here.

This is wrong:

```
printf( "Enter the student's Major Code.\n" );
scanf( " %s", &student1.major_code);

printf( " %s, %s, %f, %d, %s ", student1.student_name, 
student1.ssn_number, student1.gpa, student1.units, student1.major_code);
```

The format specifiers don't match the arguments.

You are using `%s` for `student1.major_code` which is a `char` and not a `char*`.
Use `%c` instead:

```
printf( "Enter the student's Major Code.\n" );
scanf( " %c", &student1.major_code);

printf( " %s, %s, %f, %d, %c", student1.student_name, 
student1.ssn_number, student1.gpa, student1.units, student1.major_code);
```

Comment: The answer is good, but the program will crash **before**: `scanf( " %s", &student1.major_code);` should be `scanf( " %c", &student1.major_code);`. You should edit your answer.